# Meteor js .allow list not showing

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, meteor

I am trying to implement the .allow part of meteor in an application I'm building. Before introducing it a list was displaying comments a user entered, now the comments just flash up for a second and then disappear. The comments are still being added to the collection though.
Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, I am very new to this.

Main js file:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe("ques");
  });

  Template.compose.events({
    'submit form': function (event) {
      var $body = $('#que-body');
      var $score = 1;
      event.preventDefault();

  Questions.insert({
    body: $body.val(),
    score: $score,
    created_at: Date()
  });

  $body.val('');
  }
 });

  Template.question.selected = function () {
    return Session.equals("selected_question", this._id) ? "selected" : '';
  };

  Template.question.events({
    'click': function () {
      Session.set("selected_question", this._id);
    }

  });

  Template.question.que = function(){
    return Questions.findOne(Session.get("selected"));
  };

    // Deals with up-vote, down-vote, remove buttons
  Template.list.events({
    'click .icon-thumbs-up': function(event) {
      Questions.update(Session.get("selected_question"), {$inc: {score: 1}});
    },
    'click .icon-thumbs-down': function(event) {
      Questions.update(Session.get("selected_question"), {$inc: {score: -1}});
    },
    'click .icon-remove': function(event) {
      Questions.remove(Session.get("selected_question"));
    }
  });


  Template.list.questions = Questions.find({}, {sort: {score: -1, created_at: -1}});
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.publish("ques", function(){
        return Questions.find({}, {
            fields:{ }
        })
    });
  });
}
```

The model.js file:

```
Questions = new Meteor.Collection("questions");

Questions.allow({

    insert: function(userId, que){
        return userId && que.owner === userId;
    },

    update: function(id, ques, fields, modifier){
    return true;
    },

    remove: function(id, que){
        return id && que.owner === id;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the questions (you said comments?): Your `Meteor.allow` rule is basically something that says the `question.owner` is the current logged in user's `_id`. You need to insert an `owner` when you insert your question. This is the only way (`que.owner === userId` will return `true`):

```
Questions.insert({
    owner: Meteor.userId(),
    body: $body.val(),
    score: $score,
    created_at: Date()
});
```

Make sure you ensure that only logged in users have the chance to insert questions. Either by hiding the button or having a check just before everything is inserted too:

```
if(!Meteor.userId()) {
    alert("You need to be logged in to post a question");
    return;
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks, I added the owner attribute and it displayed the list and seems to be working correctly. I have a statement in the html that only lets them insert questions if they are logged in.

Comment: Just thought I'd ask is there an easy way in meteor, possibly with the .allow, to make it so a user can upvote a question once.

Comment: You could associate their user id with the vote when voting on the client. In meteor.allow you could check if their name is in an array already on the document containing the vote and if not return true else return false